# Torsion of a Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the curve:

- $x=p \sqrt{p^2-q^2} \cos t$
- $y=q \sqrt{p^2-q^2} (1 + \sin t)$
- $z=(p^2-q^2)(1 + \sin t)$

Show that the torsion is zero.

I tried to calculate torsion by the following relation $T=([r'(t) \times r''(t)] \cdot r'''(t))\div[|r'(t) \times r''(t)|^2] $
but it is not zero so is there any mistake in my method?

Comment: You're working too hard. This curve lies in the plane of $\sqrt{p^2-q^2}y=qz$, hence automatically has torsion 0.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you please explain a little more ??

Comment: It's a standard result (see, for example, my free differential geometry text linked in my profile) that a curve (with nonzero curvature) has torsion identically 0 if and only if the curve lies in a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $r'''=-r'$ the scalar triple product is zero and hence the torsion is zero